# Changing appearance/disappearance when clicking checkboxes --> Change to Radio

Tags: javascript, html

So i basically have a script when I can click Checkboxes, Divs appear. But if I change the "checkbox" to "radio", and then click different radios, it wont hide the divs that appeared before...

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
                var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
                $("." + inputValue).toggle(); 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How to I change it so the divs disappear when the radio is unselected because I select another radio?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Either _remember_ which one you showed previously, so that you can hide that one specifically now; or hide _all_ of them first, and then show the one based on your current radio button selection.

Comment: Could you maybe give a coding example? I only need Javascript for that small part, I am not used to JavaScript so I cant code it out of an explanation.. :/

Comment: You have not shown any HTML, so we can't currently tell which would be the best way to select all the relevant elements & hide them at once. If all your divs have an additional class, besides the specific one you use to show them, then it would be something like `$(#.foobar').hide()`, or if you wanted to select them based on that they are all children of a specific parent, something like `$(#parentId > div').hide()` ... lots of possible ways, depends on the specifics.